# need selected radio/boolean fields input submitted to email - wtforms + flask

Tags: flask, wtforms

Hi I built a new project form that a user can submit which goes to my email. Currently wondering how to get only the input labels of the boolean fields the user selected (=True) sent to my email, rather than all of them. Would that involve a for loop for wtype1-5 : if True, submit. else: no submit  ?  For example, using:  form.wtype1.data for Optional Boolean fields returns True or False. I want only the labels of True inputs.  Using form.wtype1.label returns an ugly string with HTML label tags, so I had to resort to form.wtype1.description, which isn't a solution because I'm getting all values not just True ones.

## test email

From: Richard salad beeeeeeetetetetet@asdf.bnt

Static Blog Ecommerce Forums Other

Basic

Basic Template 7

This is a comments area of basic test form for input functionality

## form class and function

```
class NewProjectForm(Form):
    subject = 'New Project Request!'
    name = TextField([validators.Length(min=5, max=20)])
    email = TextField([validators.Length(min=8, max=50), validators.Email()])
    wtype1 = BooleanField(validators=[validators.Optional()], label='Static', description='Static')
    wtype2 = BooleanField(validators=[validators.Optional()], label='Blog', description='Blog')
    wtype3 = BooleanField(validators=[validators.Optional()], label='Ecommerce', description='Ecommerce')
    wtype4 = BooleanField(validators=[validators.Optional()], label='Forums', description='Forums')
    wtype5 = BooleanField(validators=[validators.Optional()], label='Other', description='Other')
    wtype = (wtype1,wtype2,wtype3,wtype4,wtype5)
    
    wpack = RadioField([validators.Required()], choices=[('SkyFly','SkyFly'),('Basic','Basic'),('Standard','Standard'),('Intermediate','Intermediate')])
    templates = RadioField([validators.Required()], choices=[('Basic Template 1','Basic Template 1'),('Basic Template 2','Basic Template 2'), \
                            ('Basic Template 3','Basic Template 3'), ('Basic Template 4','Basic Template 4'),('Basic Template 5','Basic Template 5'), \
                            ('Basic Template 6','Basic Template 6'),('Basic Template 7','Basic Template 7'),('Basic Template 8','Basic Template 8'), \
                                                    ('Basic Template 9','Basic Template 9'),('Basic Template 10','Basic Template 10'), \
                                                ('Intermd. Template 1', 'Intermd. Template 1'),('Intermd. Template 2','Intermd. Template 2')]) 
    comments = TextAreaField([validators.Length(min=10, max=400)])

@app.route('/dashboard/newproject/', methods=["GET","POST"])
def new_project():
    try:
        form = NewProjectForm()

        if request.method == "POST":
            if form.validate() == False:
                flash('Invalid! All fields are required.')
                return render_template("dashboardNewproject.html", form=form)
            
            else:
                msg = Message(form.subject, sender='form.email.data', recipients=['skyldev1@gmail.com'])
                msg.body = """
                From: %s %s \n
                %s %s %s %s %s \n %s \n  %s \n \n %s
                """ % (form.name.data, form.email.data, form.wtype1.description, form.wtype2.description, \
                       form.wtype3.description, form.wtype4.description, form.wtype5.description, \
                       form.wpack.data, form.templates.data, form.comments.data)
                mail.send(msg)
                
                flash('Congratulations! A new project has been submitted.')
                gc.collect()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the least amount of your code but make it do what you want it to do, I would do:

```
class NewProjectForm(Form):
    subject = 'New Project Request!'
    name = TextField([validators.Length(min=5, max=20)])
    email = TextField([validators.Length(min=8, max=50), validators.Email()])
    wtype1 = BooleanField(validators=[validators.Optional()], label='Static', description='Static')
    wtype2 = BooleanField(validators=[validators.Optional()], label='Blog', description='Blog')
    wtype3 = BooleanField(validators=[validators.Optional()], label='Ecommerce', description='Ecommerce')
    wtype4 = BooleanField(validators=[validators.Optional()], label='Forums', description='Forums')
    wtype5 = BooleanField(validators=[validators.Optional()], label='Other', description='Other')
    wtype = (wtype1,wtype2,wtype3,wtype4,wtype5)

    wpack = RadioField([validators.Required()], choices=[('SkyFly','SkyFly'),('Basic','Basic'),('Standard','Standard'),('Intermediate','Intermediate')])
    templates = RadioField([validators.Required()], choices=[('Basic Template 1','Basic Template 1'),('Basic Template 2','Basic Template 2'), \
                            ('Basic Template 3','Basic Template 3'), ('Basic Template 4','Basic Template 4'),('Basic Template 5','Basic Template 5'), \
                            ('Basic Template 6','Basic Template 6'),('Basic Template 7','Basic Template 7'),('Basic Template 8','Basic Template 8'), \
                                                    ('Basic Template 9','Basic Template 9'),('Basic Template 10','Basic Template 10'), \
                                                ('Intermd. Template 1', 'Intermd. Template 1'),('Intermd. Template 2','Intermd. Template 2')]) 
    comments = TextAreaField([validators.Length(min=10, max=400)])

    def wtype(self):
        return (self.wtype1,self.wtype2,self.wtype3,self.wtype4,self.wtype5)

@app.route('/dashboard/newproject/', methods=["GET","POST"])
def new_project():
    try:
        form = NewProjectForm(request.form)

        if request.method == "POST":
            if form.validate() == False:
                flash('Invalid! All fields are required.')
                return render_template("dashboardNewproject.html", form=form)

            else:
                wtype = ''
                for each in form.wtype():
                    if each.data:
                        wtype+=' '+each.description
                msg = Message(form.subject, sender='form.email.data', recipients=['skyldev1@gmail.com'])
                msg.body = """
                From: %s %s \n
                %s \n %s \n  %s \n \n %s
                """ % (form.name.data, form.email.data, wtype[1:], \
                       form.wpack.data, form.templates.data, form.comments.data)
                mail.send(msg)

                flash('Congratulations! A new project has been submitted.')
                gc.collect()
```

**EDIT**:
I made an error, but it is fixed now. I also had to make a minor modification to the form. Tested it and it works.

You may also want to remove the `Length()` validator from the `email` field (a@a.com would get rejected, for example and it already checks for a valid email) as well as changing your `name` field to just be `Required()` (some people have abnormal names).

Comment: Tried, Im getting 'UnboundField' object has no attribute 'data' .  Not sure why the tuple items says no data but each variable has data....

Comment: @KingAnu Try instantiating the form by replacing `form = NewProjectForm()` with `form = NewProjectForm(request.form)`

Comment: @KingAnu I figured out what the issues were and edited my answer.

Comment: great work man its working as desired, thank you.  youre a smart little brogrammer bugger :).